# Deleting rows using some condition in VBA Macro but the formula doesn't update

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to delete rows in VBA using some condition. The VBA works the first time but the second time it takes the original value and doesn't update. For e.g., if I run the code with 'Sprint 37', it will work the first time but if I change the value to 'Sprint 38', the code still deletes the rows from 'Sprint 37'. In addition, I also want to use user defined number to be used in the code. Any help will be great. Thanks.

```
Sub Macro4()

Worksheets("Master").Activate

    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    For Each Cell In Selection
        If Cell.Value = "Sprint 38" Then
            Rows(Cell.Row).ClearContents
        End If
    Next
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Delete

End Sub
```

Comment: If it already deleted the rows `Sprint 37`, how does it delete them again? If so, this may be due to your `Selection` useDo you mean the same row numbers are deleted? It's also unclear what you mean by a "user defined number". Like a input box for a user to enter a number?

Comment: Can you share other info? What is the shape of your table? Does table start at `A1` with the first row being a header row? Is it a 2 dimensional table? Sample data may help. I'm asking because there are much better ways to define a range in comparison to `Selection` and `xlToRight`/`xlDown`

Comment: Your code works fine, but you have to be in the top left most cell you are trying to process.   Can you find the first and last row of your data without using selection?

Comment: @urdearboy I always create a new sheet with all the data before running the code so all sprint data is there. The table starts at A1 and is two-dimensional. The only reason I used selection is the size of the table can be changed by future user. If there is a better way to select dynamic range of data, would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your table starts at cell `A1` ....

1. Clearly define your range (do not rely on `.Selection`)
2. Add your target rows (*rows to be deleted*) to a `Union` (*collection of cells*) as you loop through each cell
3. Once your loop is complete, delete the entire `Union` all at once.

---

```
Sub Jeeped()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim lr As Long, lc As Long
Dim iCell As Range, DeleteMe As Range

lr = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
lc = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

For Each iCell In ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, 1), ws.Cells(lr, lc))
    If iCell = "Spring 37" Then
        If Not DeleteMe Is Nothing Then
            Set DeleteMe = Union(iCell, DeleteMe)
        Else
            Set DeleteMe = iCell
        End If
    End If
Next iCell

If Not DeleteMe Is Nothing Then DeleteMe.EntireRow.Delete

End Sub
```